# Having issues styling a three column footer (divs inside footer tag?)

Tags: html, css, footer

I'd like to style a three-column 'fat footer' at the bottom of my site. I was able to set up the general footer tag correctly (the background color, size and positioning of the whole footer), but I am having a bit of trouble understanding how to properly style the three columns within. 
Here is my markup:

```
<footer>

        <li class="column1">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sizing Chart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Returns & Exchanges</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shipping Information</a></li>
        </li>

        <ul class="column2">
            <li>###-###-####</li>
            <li>email</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="column3">
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="fb page" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="30" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
        </ul>
</footer>
```

And here is my CSS for it:

```
footer {
letter-spacing: 0.2px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom:30px;
margin-left: -10%;
margin-right: auto;
background: #000;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
width: 112.1%;
```

}

```
a:link,
a:visited {
color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: #999;
```

}

```
.column1 {
float: left;
position: absolute; 
max-width: 950px;
}
```

the last ".column1" set is just to show you how I have been thinking I should style a column. my main issue is figuring out how to set this part up (is it ul.column1, #column1, .column1???).

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: you accidentally named you column one ul lists with li tags. Also to style in css you can just call your columns by the class names you assigned to them like so 

.column1 { background-color:#ffffff; }

Comment: `width: 112.1%;`? What for? :)

Comment: `<div class="fb-like" ...` should be in a list item `<li><div class="fb-like" ...`

Comment: Ha Morpheus I know that 112.1% is bad. For some reason my margins were off at 100% so I felt it out...how embarrassing!

Answer (score 1):

```
<footer>

        <ul class="column column1">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sizing Chart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Returns & Exchanges</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shipping Information</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="column column2">
            <li>###-###-####</li>
            <li>email</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="column column3">
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="fb page" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="30" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
        </ul>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.column { 
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 33.333%;
}

.column1 {
   /* specific styles for column 1 */
}

.column2 {
   /* specific styles for column 2 */
}

.column3 {
   /* specific styles for column 3 */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Jrod! I'm still having some trouble getting the three columns to space evenly across the footer (they are piling up in the first two columns). Any idea what the styling should look like for the individual columns? Thanks again for this!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?  I am not exactly sure what you mean.  Giving `.column` `padding:0;` and `margin:0;` could help if they aren't floating properly.  As for the individual column classes you may not even need them unless you want do something specific to those columns.

Comment: Hey heres the fiddle I made with what I've got now. http://jsfiddle.net/twniehaus/PcYXS/4/ My main issue currently is that i need the 3 columns to align to the middle 930px of the screen but I haven't been able to figure out how to adjust it to do that now. I am also still having float issues with the 3 columns (both top and left) even with all the suggestions I've been given. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
.column1 {
 // Do styling here for column one
}

.column2 {
 // Do styling here for column two
}

.column3 {
 // Do styling here for column three
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? It styles each column (`footer ul`) to have 33% width, so they are evenly spaced across the 100% width footer:

http://jsfiddle.net/CPju5/

You can also style each column individually, like Ryan said.

Answer (score 0):

Your give LI to **column1** instead of UL. Write this:

```
<ul class="column1">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            ....
</ul>
```

instead of this:

```
<li class="column1">
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                ....
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `footer` element should have `overflow:auto` in its css.

The columns can be `position: relative`.